# when is a perfect fifth interval a diminished 6th and why?

Tags: theory, intervals

I did a music theory test where I was asked the interval between F# and Db. I called the interval a perfect fifth but I was wrong. It was a diminished 6th. Can someone please can explain why this interval is not a perfect fifth since on my guitar, that is what it is!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intervals have at least two different names for the same sound.

The basic *number* of an interval is counted from the lower to the higher letter. In your case **F**-G-A-B-C-**D**, making it a **6** of some sort. Next, the gap is made smaller by F raising to F#. That would make it *minor 6*, but it's smaller again as the D is now Db. So it becomes a *diminished 6th*.

Play those two notes, and call the Db C#, and, yes, there's your P5. Problem is - just by listening to two notes, it's not enough of a clue to what their interval actually is. Even given the key, is not enough. We need to know what the note *names* are, in other words where they are *written* on the stave.

Guitarists in particular seem to have problems with this - it may have something to do with the way the frets are laid out, or the fact that the same note (sounding, but named differently) can be played in many places.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93467/discussion-on-answer-by-tim-when-is-a-perfect-fifth-interval-a-diminished-6th-an).

Answer (score 2):

Don't confuse Db and C#.  They might be on the same fret, but they are spelled differently. In practice they sound the same, but in theory they are different notes. These two notes are called *enharmonic* notes.

In theory exams, when you have to identify intervals with many accidentals, this is an easy way to identify them:

- First, remove all the accidentals: You have the interval F - D, which is a major sixth.
- Add one of the accidentals: F#-D, which is a minor sixth
- Add the second accidental: F# - Db, which is a diminished sixth.

On the guitar (or piano) a perfect fifth will sound the same as a diminished sixth, but in theory those are two different intervals, and it'd be wrong not to identify them as such, like in your case.

Answer (score 1):

An interval has the following properties:

- [the pitch interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_interval)
- [the interval number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(music)#Number)
- [the quality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(music)#Quality)

> To determine the interval between 2 notes:
>   `F#-D`

- find the *pitch interva*l: there are **7** semitones between D and F# (counting from F# to D)
- find the *interval number*: F-G-A-B-C-D -> **6**
- find the *quality*: have a look at [the main intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(music)#Main_intervals) to see that 7 semitones with interval number 6 is a **diminished sixth** `d6`

For any other interval, perform the same steps. If your interval is too exotic to be on the list of main intervals, adhere to the following rules:

- `m` and `p` can be diminished `d`
- `M` and `p` can be augmented `A`

Further tampering gets fuzzy (citation needed)

- `d` can be further diminished `dd` (doubly diminished)
- or `dd` (2x diminished)
- `A` can be further augmented`dA` (doubly augmented)
- or `AA` (2x augmented)

Comment: What would 'aa' mean?  Could it be 'da'?  'There are 7 semitones between D and F#'. Only if it's counted *from* F#.

Comment: Having so rarely met doule, and never treble, I'm not sure. But dd for double diminished should mean da for double augmented, I reckon. Not convinced with caps versus lower case.

Comment: @dfhwze I'd be very surprised if there were a standard way to write the interval shorthands for doubly diminished or more (same for augmented). I think the way you did it is better than da for doubly augmented, since the d could stand for diminished instead of doubly (even though the case-sensitive nature might help). You could also try 2d5 for a doubly diminished 5th, but I think your way would probably be understood.

Comment: @dfhwze Also, "A" is the symbol for augmented, not a.

Answer (score 0):

> ...when is a perfect fifth interval a diminished 6th and why?

Never.

This mixes up *distance* with *interval names*.

A perfect fifth `P5` and a diminished 6th `d6` are the *same distance* - 7 semi-tones.

But the *interval name* is a combination of an interval number - like *5* - and then a quality - like *perfect*. `F` to `D` is six diatonic steps so its number is 6. But when we account for the accidentals `F#` to `Db` the distance gets smaller by two semi-tones and so it is called *diminished*. It's a diminished sixth.

If it were renamed to `Gb` to `Db`, the `G` to `D` is a *5* and with 7 semi-tones distance it is *perfect*, it's a perfect fifth.

`F#` to `Db` and `Gb` to `Db` are *enharmonic equivalent* spellings.

You could say a `P5` and a `d6` are *enharmonically equal* intervals, but technically they are not the same interval.

That particular interval - `d6` - is a bit odd. Two intervals non-diatonic intervals that are relatively common and could be mis-identified are:

- augmented second `A2` which is enharmonically a minor third `m3`, it is found in the *harmonic minor* scale between scale steps `^6` and `^7`.
- augmented sixth `A6` which is enharmonically a minor seventh `m7`, it is found usually in minor keys as one of several *augemented sixth* chords. In `C` minor the basic form of this chord would be `Ab C F#` with `Ab` to `F#` being the `A6`.

Those two example can be a good way to become familiar with these enharmonic spellings with practical examples that you will encounter fairly commonly.

Comment: @dfhwze - what's p6? It was a Rover saloon car from the '70s, but was never a musical interval.